# Can generic parameters be specified when using dynamic variables?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

Consider the following code:

```
class Program {
    void Foo<T>() { }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic p = new Program();
        p.Foo();
    }
}
```

Note surprisingly, the call to p.Foo() is not valid because the dynamic binder has no way of knowing what type to use for T.  The specific failure is:

"*The type arguments for method 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.Foo()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*"

Now my question is: **is there a way to specify the generic type, or is such method simply not callable using 'dynamic'?**

Comment: I forgot to add one key point, which is that the T you want to use is only known dynamically, so it can't be passed using the standard p.Foo<int>() syntax.  What we want is p.Foo<myType>(), which is not valid.

Comment: David: I've updated my answer to include Pavel's suggestion, which makes it work even for types where you can't get hold of an instance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Jared says, you can specify it in code just as you would for a static call:

```
using System;

class Program {
    void Foo<T>() {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic p = new Program();
        p.Foo<string>();
    }
}
```

The above code prints `System.String`.

Now if you only know `T` at *execution* time, it's slightly harder. If you have an instance of it though, you could use dynamic typing and type inference together:

```
using System;

class Program {
    void Foo<T>() {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic p = new Program();
        dynamic v = GetRandomInstance();

        // Now to call p.Foo<T> where T is the type of v's value...
        Dummy(v, p);
    }

    static void Dummy<T>(T t, Program p) {
        p.Foo<T>();
    }

    static object GetRandomInstance() {
        return DateTime.Now.Hour > 10 ? "hello" : (object) 10;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Pavel came up with an amazing idea in the comments. You don't need to come up with an instance of `T`, just an array. This means you can even use type arguments where you wouldn't normally be able to *get* an instance of `T` (e.g. due to a private constructor):

```
using System;

class PrivateConstructor {
    private PrivateConstructor() {}
}

class Program {
    static void Foo<T>() {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    static void CallFooProxy<T>(T[] array) {
        Foo<T>();
    }

    static void CallFoo(Type t) {
        dynamic array = Array.CreateInstance(t, 0);
        CallFooProxy(array);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        CallFoo(typeof(PrivateConstructor));
    }
}
```

Before anyone asks - no, this doesn't let you call `Foo<Enumerable>` dynamically - you still can't use a static class as a type argument, even if you try to delay the attempt until execution time :)

If all of that fails for some reason, it's back to reflection as normal... get the method info, call `MakeGenericMethod` and invoke it.

Comment: Well you guys *implemented* the thing. Somehow just *using* it pales in comparison :)

Comment: That's pretty nifty, Jon!

Unfortunately, in my scenario I don’t have an instance of the type, I just have the System.Type, which apparently makes me out of luck!  I guess I can create a dummy instance via Activator.CreateInstance just to make the binder happy, but that assumes ctor knowledge.  I might just be better off staying with the traditional Reflection/MakeGenericMethod approach.

Still marking this as 'answer', as it's probably as good as it can get with the current C# feature.

Comment: Note that Reflection won't cover all scenarios that `dynamic` does (e.g. consider what happens if the receiver is a Python object).

Comment: If you make `Dummy<T>` use an argument of type `T[]` rather than plain `T` for deduction purposes (which should still work), you can then use `Array.CreateInstance(runtimeType, 0)` to create a dummy zero-length array regardless of presence of accessible default constructors on type `T`.

Comment: @Pavel: That's an awesome idea. Mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: @Jon: Of course I don't mind! Besides, the awesome idea was yours, I merely rode the wave :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not specify the type exactly as you would for a non-dynamic type

```
p.Foo<int>();
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. See clarification I added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it doesn't matter what type "p" is, whether you declare it as **dynamic** or as **Program**, you will receive this error.

The error is saying that the type of T cannot be inferred because there are no *parameters* of type T being passed to the method, and the method isn't part of a generic class.  In this case, there's no way for the compiler to infer what type T is.

You should be able to do the following, though:

```
class Program {
    void Foo<T>() { }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic p = new Program();
        p.Foo<int>();
    }
}
```

You just need to explicitly define the type of T when you call Foo.

Comment: Yes, it's clear why the code doesn't work and what the error means.  The question is how to pass T in scenarios where T is only known at runtime (see clarification comment in the original question).

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you specify that `T` is `dynamic`?

```
p.Foo<dynamic>();
```

Comment: Because the compiler will assume that you mean "p.Foo<object>".  "dynamic" is just "object" with the additional semantics of "generate dynamic call sites on things of this type".

Comment: dynamic is not *really* a type in the sense that it characterizes the object at compile time.  Rather, it is an Object, with *dynamic* symantecs at runtime.  Given this, I doubt that the target invocation could make use of it, since the dynamic type is unique to c# (it is not be present in IronPython or IronRuby, AFAIK).

Comment: I guess that makes sense since within Foo it's statically typed as T.